# r function alias memory space

Tags: r, function, alias

Does alias function double memory space occupied by the function definition?
Is this alternative aliasing memory saver?

```
> ss=subset
> ss(glmC, donchian==don & in_fundo==F & C_V=='C', epsilon2)
  epsilon2
1    1e-07
> ss
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("subset")
<bytecode: 0x0000000018797e70>
<environment: namespace:base>

# alternative aliasing
> ss=function(...) subset(...)
> ss
function(...) subset(...)
> ss(glmC, donchian==don & in_fundo==F & C_V=='C', epsilon2)
  epsilon2
1    1e-07
```

Comment: In the first case the `subset` "closure" is, only, referenced by `ss` (`.Internal(inspect(ss))` and `.Internal(inspect(subset))`) while in the second case you create a new "closure" with different "formals" and "body"; i.e. a different R _object_ than `subset`.

Comment: I didn´t understand "closure". In the first case, is not a copy of the function made in memory (same formals, etc.)? @alexis_laz

Comment: [Reference on closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures).

Comment: @Alex : A "closure" is a type of R functions with `formals`, `body` and, an evaluating `environment`. It is an R object like everything else. In the first case, both `ss` and `subset` symbols refer to the _same_ object, while in the second case a new function/object is created. An equivalent is to create `x = 1:5` and, then, `y = x` VS `y = x + 0L` -- in the first case both `x` and `y` refer to same object while in the second case, a new object is created. So in the first case the memory needed is just for the actual symbol `ss`. In the second case, memory for a complete new closure is needed.

Comment: tks, @alexis_laz! (in portuguese, people with same name are called xarás :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this alternative aliasing memory saver?

No, it is not.

```
ss = subset
ss1 = function(...) subset(...)

object.size(ss)
# 832 bytes
object.size(ss1)
# 1280 bytes
```

We can also using `pryr::object_size`, which may be more accurate.

```
library(pryr)
object_size(ss)
# 832 B
object_size(ss1)
# 1.62 kB
```

However, the differences are so small that it is extremely difficult to imagine a situation in which they would matter. And, if you were in such a memory-tight situation, presumably the most memory-efficient solution would be to not alias at all.

Comment: tks, @Gregor. I thought in the first case a copy of the function would be made and in the second just a call to the function.